# Optimistic Paging and separate query for COUNT?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, pagination, query-performance

I am using SQL Server 2012 `FETCH/OFFSET` after searching a lot that this will give me the best performance. But for paging to work, I need a *total count*.

There are 2 ways to achieve this:

1. Paging query can include `COUNT(*) OVER()` column
2. Separate query

Which one will be best? Here is my SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllProducts] (@PageNumber int,
@PageCount int)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        Products.[ID] AS [ID1],
        Products.[Name] AS [Name],
        Products.[Price] AS [Price],
        Products.[NewPrice] AS [NewPrice],
        Products.[ShortDescription] AS [ShortDescription],
        Products.[SKU] AS [SKU],
        Products.[ProductTypeID] AS [ProductTypeID],
        Products.[ImageID] AS [ImageID],
        Products.[Promotion] AS [Promotion],
        Products.[ParentID] AS [ParentID],
        Products.[Attributes] AS [Attributes],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Products.[ID] ASC) AS [row_number]
    FROM [dbo].[Products] AS Products
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Images] AS Images
        ON Products.[ImageID] = Images.[ID]
    ORDER BY Products.[ID] ASC
    OFFSET ((@PageNumber - 1) * @PageCount) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @PageCount ROWS ONLY;
END
```

The Products table has more than 50,000 rows, sometimes static, sometimes changing a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you need an exact count and not an approximation, and you want this to go fast without index scanning (yes, please!), a good place to start would be to create an indexed view that maintains the count of rows:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT
        COUNT_BIG(*) AS NumberOfRows
        FROM [dbo].[Products];
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_MyView
    ON dbo.MyView(NumberOfRows);
```

<sup>(Note: an `ID` column can't be added to this view and then the clustered index created on it.)</sup>

Yes, this will add a small amount of overhead to writes to the base table; it doesn't sound like that's going to be a problem in this case.

Then it's really easy and efficient to read a transactionally-consistent row count:

```
SELECT NumberOfRows FROM dbo.MyView WITH(NOEXPAND);
```

which can either be included in the same query, or separately. Personally, I'd try to keep it separate and return the value as an `OUTPUT` parameter. In either case, for an exact count, I'd strongly recommend using snapshot isolation to avoid out-of-sync issues.

This type of structure could also be created with a user table and a trigger, or a "business logic" approach... but because of the number of moving parts in either of those solutions, I really wouldn't recommend them unless there's no other choice.

---

If you do go this route, be sure to patch SQL Server to at least:

- Cumulative Update 7 for SQL Server 2012 SP2
- Cumulative Update 1 for SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 1
- Cumulative Update 8 for SQL Server 2014 RTM

See the Knowledge Base article:

[Incorrect results are returned in an indexed view after an Insert or Delete operation on the base table occurs in SQL Server 2014](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3067896)

For more details and background, see [An Indexed View Bug with Scalar Aggregates](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/04/sql-indexes/an-indexed-view-bug-with-scalar-aggregates) by Paul White.