# How to get accurate row counts in partitions in a table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, partitioning

I am trying to fetch row counts in each partition for a table. But I got confused as in sys.partitions row counts is on basis of indexes.

So how can I get exact row count for partitions in a table.

Comment: Is the number of rows changing frequently? Do you need to do this once, or repeatedly? My answer [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63432/2718) may help you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to ignore index_id with values that are not 0 (heap) or 1 (clustered index)

```
SELECT rows  FROM sys.partitions 
WHERE object_id = object_id('name of table') 
AND index_id < 2
```

Comment: This count is non-transactional, which may make it unsuitable for an "exact" count.

Comment: Yes.  The only true way of getting a count of rows from a table is to do a select count(*), but the OP wants row counts per partition.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx